# Restart while loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

So i have a program that prints a different thing depending on the input(choice)
Like this

```
choice = int(input("Choose a function from 1 to 3: "))
while(True):
if choice == 1:
   print("You chose 1")
elif choice == 2:
   print("You chose 2")
elif choice == 3:
   print("Shutting down")
   break
```

At the moment it keeps on printing the print statement when I choose 1 or 2, can I make it so that it only prints once(I think you can do this by adding more loops but I hope there is a better alternative)

So I would like that the program ask for the choice again

Thanks!

Comment: move the `choice = ...` stuff inside the loop.

Comment: I don't really know what are you trying to accomplish with your code. In the case that you are trying to choose once, and print once, you don't need a loop. In the case that you want to choose, print and then choose again, put the choice inside the while loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot @luk2302 and Tranbi, I don't know how I didn't figure that out myself, it works now!

Comment: `while` is not a function, so you don't need the parentheses. `while(True):` should be `while True:`.

Answer (score 2):

There's indentation error in your code. Fix that and also, the input statement should be moved inside the while loop so that it can keep asking again and again. Your edited code:

```
while True:
    choice=int(input("Enter your choice= "))
    if choice==1:
        print("You've chosen 1")
    elif choice==2:
        print("You've chosen 2")
    elif choice==3:
        print("Shutting down")
        break
```

Comment: I think the break statement should be inside the elif because (assuming the common sense) why would you want to break the loop the first time it runs? The break statement should be in the choice==3, because 3 is shutting down the program, aka breaking the loop.

Comment: Yeah I mistook the question, edited

Answer (score 2):

You only deffine the variable once and then just let the loop run all the time. Try to move "choice" into the loop so that "choice" is always redefined.

(Also you should make `while True` and not `while(True)`.)

This should work:

```
while True:
    choice = int(input("Choose a function from 1 to 3: "))
    if choice == 1:
       print("You chose 1")
    elif choice == 2:
       print("You chose 2")
    elif choice == 3:
       print("Shutting down")
       break
```

Comment: You should have indentation of code in the body of your loop, right now it is incorrect Python code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the input variable inside loop to take multiple inputs.

```
while(True):
    choice = int(input("Choose a function from 1 to 3: "))
    if choice == 1:
          print("You chose 1")
    elif choice == 2:
           print("You chose 2")
    elif choice == 3:
        print("Shutting down")
        break
```